# How to check whether email is successfully sent or rejected?

Tags: laravel

I am using this function in laravel to send a mail.

```
Mail::send('blah', $data, function($message) {
// content
});
```

I want to check whether the email successfully sent or rejected.

I tried mail:failures() but it always show successfully sent.

Comment: This is not a thing the nature of email lets you do. You should read up more on email deliverability.

Comment: @user2357112 Mailgun will report if it was delivered or not.

Comment: I believe in laravel, `Mail::send` will throw if it's not accepted by mail provider. Not sure what backend you're using, but I'm using Mailgun, and I'm pretty sure if it returns a non-200, Laravel will throw. That said... that doesn't mean that your email was delivered, just that it was queued. You can log into mailgun to see if it was delivered. Not sure if there's a laravel api method for that or not, but you probably wouldn't want to do it in the same request cycle anyway -- it could take awhile. Mailgun can queue for awhile.

Comment: You can also enable "open tracking" inside Mailgun to see if the email message was *actually* opened, or implement a tracking pixel yourself.

Comment: @mpen: Mailgun cannot know for sure; delivery failures can be silent. You can tell if the user opens it with a tracking image (if the user's email client shows images), but if they don't open it (or if they don't load the tracking image), you can't tell for sure if it was delivered.

Comment: @user2357112 Fair enough. Mailgun does use the words "Accepted" and "Delivered" though. I guess that just means the receiving mailbox didn't immediately reject it, not that it'll necessarily show up in the person's inbox.

Comment: well, i just need a status to notify user either the email is sent or not. Just curious Mail::send() didnt throw any error as long as the 'email format' is correct.